# Why doesnt my C# extension method work in this console app?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have the console app:

```
namespace LicenceCreator
{
    class Program
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }    

        public static string TrimTextAndAppendDots(
            this string stringArg, int maxLengthArg)
        {
            string retString;

            if (stringArg.Length > maxLengthArg)
            {
                retString = stringArg.Substring(0, maxLengthArg) + "...";
            }
            else
            {
                retString = stringArg;
            }

            return retString;
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason the extension method isnt picked up when I call it from a string in the main method any ideas why?

Comment: Did you put a break point and see what is the exact problem...?

Comment: @Misam This is a compilation issue, how you would put a break point?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program - currently you've shown a method without an enclosing class, and no example of trying to call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that by "isn't picked up", you mean "the compiler complains that it can't find it". Then:

The extension method must be in a "static" class and you must have a "using" directive pointing to the namespace of that class. Do you?

If it's "the compiler doesn't complain but the string doesn't change" then maybe you are calling it as

```
 myString.TrimTextAndAppendDots(10);
```

instead of

```
 myString = myString.TrimTextAndAppendDots(10);
```

Comment: @Pete2k: In that case the answer is simple: C# does not allow you to specify extension methods in non-static classes. Move the extension method to its own class (a static class).

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods must be declared within a static class.

- Is extension method's class static?

In order to call an extension method, declaring class' namespace must be referenced:

- Have you added class assembly reference?
- Have you declared the corresponding "using" statement for extension methods class' namespace?

---

UPDATE:

Answering to your comment, I find my answer correct anyway, but now we can add:

- Is your "Program" class static? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Extensions have to be on a static class, just like this:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string TrimTextAndAppendDots(this string stringArg, int maxLengthArg)
    {
        string retString = "";

        if (stringArg.Length > maxLengthArg)
        {
            retString = stringArg.Substring(0, maxLengthArg) + "...";
        }
        else
        {
            retString = stringArg;
        }

        return retString;
    }
}
```

And finally you have to declare `StringExtension` with `using` statement wherever you want to use said extension methods